# Error when connecting to local SQL server from C# application

Tags: c#, sql

In PC1 I created a C# application wins forms which uses local SQL server database then I deployed my application to `.exe` file using Visual studio. Then I installed the `exe` file into same PC (PC1) and I works fine and can connect to SQL database using the following connection string:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local; Initial Catalog=mydb; Integrated Security=True");
```

The problem is: when I went to another PC (PC2) I installed SQL server and I manually attached the same database (mydb) and then installed my application but it gives me the following error:

[image: screenshot]

However, when I change the name of PC2 same as PC1 the application can connect and it works well.It means if I want to install my application in different PC then I have to name that PC same name as the original PC which I created my C# in (PC1).

why is this error happening? I mean why do I have to set other PCs to have the same name as the original PC (PC1). Please help me how to fix this eror. Thank you

Comment: You really shouldn't ask the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597680/why-cant-i-connect-to-the-sql-server-database-when-i-create-setup-file-in-visua

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have the same name on different PCs to have a C# program connected to a SQL server. One thing I would like to point out, maybe you are aware maybe you are not. If you install the database on EACH machine they programs won't share the data (again, this might sound silly but just in case).

To the error itself, if you installed SQL Server on machine PC2 go to Services and double check that the SQL Server INSTANCE is the same as the one you set up on your connection string. You don't have to even have the same database name it could be totally different on each machine, the important thing there is to have the correct connection string (you should have the connection string as a configuration that you can easily change from a `.conf` file.

Just double check on PC2 that the server is working as expected (check services and Event Viewer for any errors that might popup) you can also try instead of local 127.0.0.1

Comment: @ ProgrammerV5 . yes the server on pc2 working well. I had to set the same name of PC1 as PC2 otherwise the app won't work. and I specified that the Data Source=localhost so it should work but I don't know why. any idea? thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate Sql Server and Windows authentication in your sql server and change your connection string from integrated security to user/password authentication.

[image]

Data Source needs to be changed either to IP or to the name of the server